# My Android App is uploaded in another market without my permission

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded an Android App on Google Play Store and with a search today i can see this: http://www.androidappsgame.com/library-quiz/el

How come that my android app is uploaded to androidappsgame.com without my permission?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Comment: I disagree because it does deal with distribution, and many people get a little confused about how that works.

Comment: Questions regarding app distribution channels are [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may not help, but make sure to check that first box in your console

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The app is NOT on that store.  That store is an aggregate site that grabs info from Google Play and makes it searchable.  And it's not a very good one at that.

For the record, all of my apps are there too.  I just looked.  Even my newest ones are there.

You don't need to worry about anyone taking your app from Play and making it available elsewhere.  It's just not gonna happen.  And even if it did, 99% of devices out there have the system secured so you can't install stuff like that anyway.

Comment: I dont worry about redistributing my app(this cannot be done without the keystore file i know) but the thing is at least not nice to be advertised with other people efforts